# protractor cannot find environments/environment

Tags: intellij-idea, protractor, angular-test

I am running my `spec` from `IntelliJ` by clicking on the green triangle in the left gutter. It seems it starts `protractor`. My test cases don't run unfortunately. The `Chrome` window opens for a moment only. I see the following error on the `IntelliJ` screen

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:...\bin\protractor" "C:\...\protractor-intellij\lib\protractor-intellij-config.js" "--intellijOriginalConfigFile=C:...\web\ui\protractor.conf.js" --disableChecks --specs "C:\...\ui\src\app\nav-component\nav-component.component.spec.ts" "--grep=^NavComponentComponent "
(node:22316) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[17:25:17] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:25:17] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
(node:22316) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[17:25:21] E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'environments/environment'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    ...
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RSI\Documents\manu data\Documents\manu\codingjedi\code_related\code\frontend\web\ui\src\app\web-to-backend-interface.service.ts:2:1)
    [17:25:21] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

    Process finished with exit code 4
```

Why `protractor` can't find the file?

The tests work fine if I use `ng test --source-map=false`. The issue arises when I use `protractor`. Even though I am using `protractor`, I am not running e-2-e tests.

Comment: it's not clear what your configuration looks like. If protractor is not a right test runner for your tests, what test runner has to be used instead? did you try using the appropriate run configuration in IDEA? Sample project that shows up the issue would be helpful

Comment: post your config or whatever file where you require 'environments/environment'